# why pyinstaller never compile private module in project?

Tags: python, module, compilation, package, pyinstaller

question:::why pyinstaller never compile private module in project?

I wonder if issues system could help me with this.... ....

system info:

- `macOS`: `Darwin iMac 21.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 17:33:23 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 iMac19,1 Darwin`
- `Python`:`3.9.7`
- `pyinstaller`:`4.7`

**problem:::pyinstaller never compile module in project to dist**

project struct:

project name is: `testing`

- `testing`

  - `cmd`

    - `__init__.py`
    - `Oracle.py`
  - `main.py`

`__init__.py` 's content is empty.

Oracle.py's content:

```
def version(args):
    print("v0.1")

class OracleExec():
    @staticmethod
    def init(subparser):
        print("---make oracle exec ---")
```

`main.py`'s content:

```
    from cmd.Oracle import OracleExec

    if __name__ == '__main__':        
        OracleExec.init()
```

using command `python3 main.py` , everything **work fine**.

but , run pyi under testing folder:
`pyinstaller main.py`
then calling compile target bin file:
`./dist/main/main`

errror message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 12, in  from cmd.Oracle import OracleExec ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmd.Oracle'; 'cmd' is not a package [37484] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

files in dist folder:

> Python base_library.zip lib-dynload libcrypto.1.1.dylib liblzma.5.dylib libmpdec.3.dylib libreadline.8.dylib libssl.1.1.dylib main